# using ns() for spline prediction

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to reproduce the upper left plot of Figure 5.4(page 147) of "Elements of Statistical Learning" of Hastie et al (2008).

It is easy enough to do it this way:

```
library(splines)
library(gam)
sa=read.table("http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/datasets/SAheart.data",
    sep=",",head=T,row.names=1)
mdl=glm(chd~ns(sbp,4)+ns(tobacco,4)+ns(ldl,4)+famhist+ns(obesity,4)+ns(age,4),data=sa,family=binomial())
plot.gam(mdl,terms="ns(sbp, 4)")
```

which gives the desired plot.

However, if I try to apply my crude understanding of the approach directly:

```
xvar=seq(min(sa$sbp),max(sa$sbp),length.out=200)
basis=ns(xvar,4)
sbpnames=c("ns(sbp, 4)1",  "ns(sbp, 4)2",  "ns(sbp, 4)3",  "ns(sbp, 4)4")
plot(xvar,basis%*%mdl$coef[sbpnames],type="l")
```

the plot is not the same.  Would anyone know why this is?  All feedback much appreciated.

Comment: `mdl` is not a `gam` object, it is created using `glm` not `gam`.

Comment: do you mean use of glm in plot.gam()? that should be ok in that plot.gam() can also accept lm and glm objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fact that they are centered on different values for their y-values relates to a question that Simon Wood answered on R-help in the last week. A question came up about the implications of using '+0' in a formula for gam, and (hoping this to be a reasonably accurate summary... ) [Simon's answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-October/326052.html) was that spline fits were assumed to have had their Intercept values subtracted from the fitted values. I assume he would have made a similar assumption for plotting routines. He basically implied that adding +0 was just confusing things and advised not to do it.

The "horizontal shifting" is related to the fact that the knot location is chosen to produce equal quantiles for knot locations and your "newdata" is uniformly distributed across the range of blood pressure, whereas the original data was right-skewed with a median in a different location. This is an effect of the `ns` function and could be "fixed" if you instead specified the same knots for both runs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There appears to be more going on than missing intercept (if I am understanding your post correctly) in that there is also some horizontal shifting.

Comment: Thanks yes that was it for the "horizontal shift".  I am still working on the y-shift, as the intercept is not lining up (the basis matrix has first row equal zero which fixes the curve on the y-axis at the smallest x-value and it is not just a matter of adding back the intercept of the fitted regression model).

Comment: You are probably missing the effects of the other covariates. Try to compare your two methods with a simpler model that includes only systolic blood pressure.